# How to make a regular expression that allows digits and only one special character?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input text and I want to allow only numbers(positive and negative) with only one special character for each "." and "-".
For example you can have -12.30, but -12...20 or --12.40 it is not allowed.

Currently I have this:

```js
value.replace(/[^\d|.-]/g, "");
```

which allows multiple "." and "-".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this

```
^[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$
```

[image]

```js
let testStr = (str) => /^[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(str)

console.log(testStr('123.12'))
console.log(testStr('-123..123'))
console.log(testStr('---12332'))
```

Comment: Ok. I understand, but I need to replace everything that is not matching this regular expression. So I can negate this and replace with ""? Like I did above(value.replace(/RegExp/, ""))

Answer (score 3):

As you don't need the `+` before the number, a simpler one is `^-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$`

- `^` = start of the line
- `-?` = make `-` optional
- `\d+` = between at least 1 digit and unlimited digits
- `(?:)` = non-capturing group
- `(?:)?` = optional non-capturing group
- `(?:\.\d+)` = optional non-capturing group that contains one `.` and between 1 and unlimited digits, after the `.`